# Записать условие, которое является истинным, когда целое А не кратно трем и оканчивается нулем

Tags: pascalabc.net

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Записать условие, которое является истинным, когда целое А не кратно
трем и оканчивается нулем.

Comment: а вы точно понимаете что делаете? Переменных нет, условие бредовое, после условия оператора нет. `while` вообще не к месту...

Comment: у меня именно с этой задачей проблема , а остальные  я хорошо пишу , не могли бы вы мне написать решение?

Comment: @Алина что за ерунда. Если вы `остальное пишите` нормально, то эта задача не вызовет у вас проблем. А математику (если вы её не знаете) можно поискать в интернете

Answer (score 1):

Одна из главных ошибок (помимо синтаксиса) - нет проверок условия:

> А не кратно трем и оканчивается нулем

```
program TrueFalse;
var
  x: integer;
begin
  Writeln('Для выхода введите 666...');
  x := ReadlnInteger('Введите число: ');
  While (x <> 666) do
    begin
      If ((x mod 3 <> 0) and (x mod 10 = 0)) Then
        Writeln('TRUE - условие выполнено!')
      Else
        Writeln('FALSE - число не удовлетворяет условию!');
      x := ReadlnInteger('Введите число: ');
    end;
  Writeln('Выход');
  Read();
end.
```

Comment: а где была ошибка синтаксиса?

Comment: @Grundy `if ... then false` например. Переменная `A` объявлена, но не используется, но это не совсем ошибка.

Comment: а так нельзя разве? :) мне вообще показалось что там `else` было и просто пропущен код для веток.

Comment: @Grundy компилятор ругается `Ожидалось имя процедуры или функции`